# JQuery Slider - Similar to www.internetmarketinginc.com

Tags: plugin-development

I am looking to add some functionality to a JQuery Slider for Wordpress.  I would like to have both navigation styles present like they have done on http://www.internetmarketinginc.com/.

I'm not sure how to tie the meta data (Slide title) and the dot navigation together.

If I need to present more info, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

If you do a quick google search, you'll find plenty of sliders available for WordPress. So - while this borders on the line of just doing your own research, there are several options available,  like:

- [Soliloquy](http://soliloquywp.com/)
- [WooSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/wooslider/)